# Merging Datasets Without Losing Data

Tags: r, merge

I have several datasets with different numerical observations of species at certain points. But if a species was not observed at a point, then the point does not exist in the data for that species. I want to merge these datasets so that I can analyze the species composition at each point, but want a value of 0 to be input if the species was not observed at the point.

Not sure how to go about this. Tried using the merge function, but if there are no observations at that point in one of the species datasets, the point is lost.

Species 1:

```
Point, Species1
1, 19
3, 12
4, 11
6, 23
```

Species 2:

```
Point, Species2
2, 10
3, 20
5, 12
6, 25
```

Desired Result:

```
Point, Species1, Species2
1, 19, 0
2, 0, 10
3, 12, 20
4, 11, 0
5, 0, 12
6, 23, 25
```

Comment: Please include example data that shows how your data looks in your question.

Comment: Just `merge` and fix holes with `ifelse(is.na(.),0,.)`.

Comment: Use `all=TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dplyr::full_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html):

```
require(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Point = c(1,3,4,6), Species1 = c(19,12,11,23))
df2 <- data.frame(Point = c(2,3,5,6), Species2 = c(10,20,12,25))

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2) %>% 
  replace_na(list(Species1=0, Species2=0)) %>%
  arrange(Point)

  Point Species1 Species2
1     1       19        0
2     2        0       10
3     3       12       20
4     4       11        0
5     5        0       12
6     6       23       25
```

Comment: I prefer 'join_all(list(dfs), type = "full)' for later cases when you need to join more data.frames.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `merge` with `all=True`

```
s=merge(df1,df2,on='Point',all=T)
s[is.na(s)]=0
s
  Point Species1 Species2
1     1       19        0
2     2        0       10
3     3       12       20
4     4       11        0
5     5        0       12
6     6       23       25
```